# How do I change a user's DN in LDAP?

Tags: ldap, apache-directory

So all of the users in our LDAP have a DN like so:

```
DN: uid=firstname.lastname,ou=users,dc=companyname,dc=com
```

I want to add a new user in ApacheDirectoryStudio, so I create a new entry in the "Users" ou and add all the attributes that other users have.  When I'm done, even though the attribute list looks the same, the DN is like this:

```
DN: cn=firstname+homeDirectory=/home/firstname.lastname+loginShell=/bin/bash+mail=firstname.lastname@company.com+sn=firstname+uid=firstname.lastname+userPassword=password,ou=users,dc=companyname,dc=com
```

I don't seem to be able to edit the DN and the new user can't log in like normal.  What am I missing here?

Comment: @Roshith Edit rejected. You have misunderstood the question and would have completely destroyed the meaning of the post.

Comment: I suggest you will have to delete this mangled entry and do it again properly, whatever 'properly' means at your site. It doesn't mean putting every attribute name and value into the DN.

Comment: In that case, I guess a better question would be: how do I enter an attribute/value without  adding it to the DN?